# ES6 access this in class inheritance with prototype

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype

I am trying to break large nodejs class files into smaller ones by using prototyping. It works, as long as I do not access `this` variables in a super-class.

This code has two classes: **ClassB** extends **ClassA**. In the constructor of **ClassB** we pass a variable that **ClassA**, the super-class, set to `this.page`. We then try to access `this.page` from a prototype **functionA**.

```
class ClassA  {
    constructor(page) {
        this.page = page
        console.log('[classA/constructor] has page', this.page)

    }

    /*
     *  Example A: This works!
     */
    // functionA = () => {
    //     console.log("has page", this.page)
    // }

    /*
     *  Example B: This works!
     */
    // functionA = function() {
    //     console.log("has page", this.page)
    // }

    /*
     *  Example C: This does not work!
     */
    // functionA() {
    //     console.log("has page", this.page)
    // }
}

/*
* Example D: This is what I really want to get working... does not work
*/
ClassA.prototype.functionA = function functionA() {
    console.log('[classA/functionA] has page', this.page)
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {
    constructor(page) {
        console.log('[classB/constructor] has page', page)
        super(page)
    }
}

ClassB.prototype.functionA = function () {
    console.log('[classB/functionA] has page', this.page)
    this.__proto__.functionA()
}

const classB = new ClassB('YES!');
classB.functionA();
```

Uncommenting and running Example A and example B works fine and gives the following, correct, output:

```
[classB/constructor] has page YES!
[classA/constructor] has page YES!
has page YES!
```

When switching to prototype (Example D, the uncommented one in the code) it break, output is:

```
[classB/constructor] has page YES!
[classA/constructor] has page YES!
[classB/functionA] has page YES!
[classB/functionA] has page undefined
[classA/functionA] has page undefined
```

I figure it has to do with binding, as Example C does not work either. But I can not understand why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling

```
this.__proto__.functionA()
```

is the problem.  You're calling `functionA()` in a way that will not have the right object in `this` inside of `functionA()`.  Calling it that way will have `this.__proto__` as the value of `this` inside of `functionA()`.  That is clearly not what you want.

I don't know why you're using `this.__proto__.functionA()` in the first place rather than `this.functionA()`, but you could force the right `this` with:

```
this.__proto__.functionA().call(this)
```

---

In case you didn't realize, when you call `obj.method()`, Javsacript sets the value of `this` inside of `method()` to `obj`.  So, when you do `this.__proto__.functionA()`, you're telling JS to set the value of `this` inside of `functionA()` to `this.__proto__` which is not what you want.

---

If what you're trying to do is to call classA's version of functionA from within classB's functionA override, then you would do that like this:

```
ClassB.prototype.functionA = function () {
    console.log('[classB/functionA] has page', this.page)
    ClassA.prototype.functionA.call(this);
}
```

And, if you use ES6 class syntax for defining your methods (instead of prototype manipulation), you would just use:

```
super.functionA();
```

to call the base class version of that function.

Comment: `this.__proto__.functionA()` is also dangerous in the general class-inheritance because `class ClassC extends ClassB {}; new ClassC().functionA()` would be a recursive call because `this.__proto__ === ClassB.prototype`. It needs to be `ClassA.prototype.functionA.call(this)` or even `Reflect.get(ClassA.prototype, "functionA", this).call(this);` to be safe.

Comment: Yeah I tried using .call(this), however it will cause an infinite-loop and crash (Maximum call stack..). And removing this.__proto__ will also make it loop. I guess it keeps calling itself.

Comment: @mathan - Well, you can't put `this.__proto__.functionA().call(this)` inside of the definition of `functionA()`.   That is clearly infinite recursion so there is no point.  Other than intellectual curiosity, you should not be calling `this.__proto__.functionA()` anyway.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: @mathan - See what I added to the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks, the `ClassA.prototype.functionA.call(this)` does works. And I see the problem with the recursiveness with my original solution. However, the `super.functionA()`, does not. (That would be the most logical imo and a really nice way of doing it..).

Comment: @mathan - `super.functionA()` requires that you use ES6 class definitions for your methods, not direct manipulation of the prototype (as I say in my answer).  Examples [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super).

Comment: @jfriend00: ahh.. did not read your comment on the super. The whole point is to require in functions to split large nodejs-files into smaller files. So what I do is this: `ClassB.prototype.functionA = require('./functionA') `. I would love to use super as it makes the code much cleaner, but I could not figure out how to do this without prototyping. So I guess I am stuck with prototyping.

Comment: btw, small typo in your code capital C for classA.prototype. Thanks again, I will mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: @mathan - OK, fixed.  FYI, you can directly propose edits like that.  I think you would enjoy using the ES6 `class` syntax much better than direct prototype manipulation, though it is useful to understand how the prototype actually works since the `class` syntax generates the same prototype.

Comment: @mathan - I would guess you just need to break your large method into smaller pieces and put the shell definition in a `class` structure, including where you would do `super()` and then call out to imported pieces from within the main method definition.  No one method should be that large anyway.